# Filtering bitbucket url to get to specific method

Tags: java, automated-tests, bitbucket

I have a test report and I want the reader to be able to click on a specific test method and reach that method in bitbucket. I can only figure out how to filter by using line numbers, not using the name. Is there some way to do it?

Comment: On the [official BitBucket hyperlink documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/hyperlink-to-source-code-in-bitbucket/) there seems to be only the mentioned line linking. The only way I can think of doing this is to request the file beforehand, search it for the method and then put the line number into your hyperlink.